# Como puedo hacer para crear un filtro por varias condiciones en simultáneo con diferentes <select>?

Tags: reactjs, filtro

Estoy hace días intentando hacer una función que haga lo que dice el título pero no he podido.
[image: De esta manera se ve el buscador con las publicaciones que quiero filtrar:]

Quiero lograr que el filtrado sea dinámico, osea que pueda usar todos a la vez así como algunos si y otros no.

Tengo un componente Filter que envía por props el estado de cada uno de los inputs. De esta manera, el botón "buscar" quedaría así:

```
      <button
    className="boton-buscar"
    onClick={() => {
      props.filtrar(depto, inmueble, estado, dormitorios);
    }}
  >
    BUSCAR
  </button>
```

En cuanto a la función filtrar, en el componente padre, hasta ahora la estoy formulando así:

```
  const filter = (depto, inmueble, estado, dormitorios) => {
const arrayFiltrado = [...arrayOriginal].filter((propiedad) => {
  if (propiedad.departamento !== "") {
    if (propiedad.departamento === depto) {
      return propiedad;
    }
  }
  if (propiedad.tipo !== "") {
    if (propiedad.tipo === inmueble) {
      return propiedad;
    }
  }
});
setArrayPublicaciones(arrayFiltrado);
```

};

Como ven, está incompleta en cuanto a las propiedades, pero en principio quiero probar filtrando dinámicamente por dos propiedades (en este caso depto e inmueble) para ver si funciona y aún no lo he logrado.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda, saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer así, he supuesto que depto, inmueble, estado son strings y dormitorios un numero. si no es así habría que modificar alguna condicion en el if.

```
const filter = (depto, inmueble, estado, dormitorios) => {
    const arrayFiltrado = arrayOriginal.filter(elem => {
        if(((depto?.length > 0 && elem.departamento.toLowerCase() === depto.toLowerCase()) || !depto || depto.length === 0) &&
            ((inmueble?.length > 0 && elem.inmueble.toLowerCase() === inmueble.toLowerCase()) || ! inmueble || inmueble.length === 0) && 
            ((estado?.length > 0 && elem.estado.toLowerCase() === estado.toLowerCase()) || !estado || estado.length === 0) && 
            ((dormitorios && elem.dormitorios === dormitorios) || !dormitorios)){
            return elem;
        }
    }

}
```